# JVM smart memory pool resizing

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

A while ago I came about this article explaining how modern JVM have an option to automatically configure the size of the different memory pools.

I'm now trying to pinpoint this again, but cannot find the article or other hints to this option.

How to configure the JVM to smart optimize the size of the memory pools?

Thanks

---

Can't find the blog post (was an nice analysis of the feature), but I found this:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html

Going to try

`-XX:+UseAdaptiveSizePolicy 
together with:
-XX:GCTimeRatio=nnn
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=nnn`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is adaptive size policy you read about. VM option is -XX:+UseAdaptiveSizePolicy.

Also It is not used often as it adds extra cost of calculating size and you can print size using -XX:+PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy